# Update select option on click and update selected options on save click

Tags: javascript

I have some SVG squares that when I click on them it selects that square and changes the food type below it. it also updates if I select an option from the dropdown. this is all working well. but I also need to update the dropdown option if I click on a square. I then need to update the second square with all the values that I have selected in the first instance. I am new to Javascript so please don't bash my code as I know it can be better. I also feel I'm repeating myself in the select event listener and the button event listener. Help would be appreciated to get this to work as I'm now stuck on what to do.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.rec-btn');
const saveBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const selectOption = document.getElementById('blocks');
const blockName = document.querySelector('.block-name');
const foodType = document.getElementById('foods');
const foodTypeSelected = document.getElementById('foodsSelected');

const foods = [
  fruit = [
    'apples',
    'pairs',
    'banannas',
    'peaches'
  ],
  veg = [
    'broccoli',
    'carrots',
    'beans',
    'spinach'
  ],
  dairy = [
    'milk',
    'cheese',
    'yogurt',
    'ice-cream'
  ],
  meat = [
    'beef',
    'lamb',
    'pork',
    'chicken'
  ]
]
foodType.innerHTML = foods[0];
foodTypeSelected.innerHTML = foods[0];
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.classList.remove('selected');
  });

  e.currentTarget.classList.add('selected');


  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.blockTarget === 'block1') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[0];
  }
  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.blockTarget === 'block2') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[1];
  }
  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.blockTarget === 'block3') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[2];
  }
  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.blockTarget === 'block4') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[3];
  }
}

selectOption.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

  if (e.target.id !== 'blocks') return;

  btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.classList.remove('selected');
    let currentBtn = btn.dataset.blockTarget;

    if (btn.dataset.blockTarget === e.target.value) {
      btn.classList.add('selected');
    }
  });

  if (e.target.value === 'block1') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[0];
  }
  if (e.target.value === 'block2') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[1];
  }
  if (e.target.value === 'block3') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[2];
  }
  if (e.target.value === 'block4') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[3];
  }

});

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});


// save the selection to updated the selected state

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.wrapper__inner+.wrapper__inner {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.rec-btn {
  display: block;
}

.rec-btn:hover rect {
  fill: red;
}

.rec-btn.selected rect {
  fill: cyan;
}

.block-name {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.block.selected {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select id="blocks" class="select">
    <option value="block1">Block 1</option>
    <option value="block2">Block 2</option>
    <option value="block3">Block 3</option>
    <option value="block4">Block 4</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="wrapper__inner">
    <div class="image__wrapper">
      <svg width="224px" height="224px" viewBox="0 0 224 224" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <title>Group</title>
        <g id="Crowd-Funding" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-1107.000000, -593.000000)" fill="#4163BB">
            <g id="Group" transform="translate(1107.000000, 593.000000)">
              <a class="rec-btn selected" href="" data-block-target="block1"><rect id="block1" class="block" x="112" y="0" width="112" height="112"></rect></a> 
              <a class="rec-btn" href="" data-block-target="block2"><rect id="block2" class="block" x="112" y="112" width="112" height="112"></rect></a>
              <a class="rec-btn" href="" data-block-target="block3"><rect id="block3" class="block" x="0" y="0" width="112" height="112"></rect></a>
              <a class="rec-btn" href="" data-block-target="block4"><rect id="block4" class="block" x="0" y="112" width="112" height="112"></rect></a>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
      <div id="foods" class="block-name">Block 1</div>

      <button class="btn">Save</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="wrapper__inner">
    <svg width="224px" height="224px" viewBox="0 0 224 224" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <title>Group</title>
      <g id="Crowd-Funding" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-1107.000000, -593.000000)" fill="#4163BB">
          <g id="Group" transform="translate(1107.000000, 593.000000)">
            <rect id="block1" class="block selected" x="112" y="0" width="112" height="112"></rect>
            <rect id="block2" class="block" x="112" y="112" width="112" height="112"></rect>
            <rect id="block3" class="block" x="0" y="0" width="112" height="112"></rect>
            <rect id="block4" class="block" x="0" y="112" width="112" height="112"></rect>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>

    <div id="foodsSelected" class="block-name">Block 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the selected attribute from the option (if one is selected) with `removeAttr('selected')` and then you have to set it to the option (`selected = true`) with the same value like the dataset.blockTarget from the clicked square. You can select the option with the value in that form: `document.querySelector('#blocks option[value="block1"]')`.

**Working example**:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.rec-btn');
const saveBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const selectOption = document.getElementById('blocks');
const blockName = document.querySelector('.block-name');
const foodType = document.getElementById('foods');
const foodTypeSelected = document.getElementById('foodsSelected');

const foods = [
  fruit = [
    'apples',
    'pairs',
    'banannas',
    'peaches'
  ],
  veg = [
    'broccoli',
    'carrots',
    'beans',
    'spinach'
  ],
  dairy = [
    'milk',
    'cheese',
    'yogurt',
    'ice-cream'
  ],
  meat = [
    'beef',
    'lamb',
    'pork',
    'chicken'
  ]
]
foodType.innerHTML = foods[0];
foodTypeSelected.innerHTML = foods[0];

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.classList.remove('selected');
  });

  e.currentTarget.classList.add('selected');

  let selected = document.querySelector('#blocks option[selected]');
  if (selected) selected.removeAttr('selected');

  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.blockTarget === 'block1') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[0];
    document.querySelector('#blocks option[value="block1"]').selected = true;
  }
  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.blockTarget === 'block2') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[1];
    document.querySelector('#blocks option[value="block2"]').selected = true;
  }
  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.blockTarget === 'block3') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[2];
    document.querySelector('#blocks option[value="block3"]').selected = true;
  }
  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.blockTarget === 'block4') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[3];
    document.querySelector('#blocks option[value="block4"]').selected = true;
  }
}

selectOption.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (e.target.id !== 'blocks') return;

  btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.classList.remove('selected');
    let currentBtn = btn.dataset.blockTarget;

    if (btn.dataset.blockTarget === e.target.value) {
      btn.classList.add('selected');
    }
  });

  if (e.target.value === 'block1') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[0];
  }
  if (e.target.value === 'block2') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[1];
  }
  if (e.target.value === 'block3') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[2];
  }
  if (e.target.value === 'block4') {
    foodType.innerHTML = foods[3];
  }
});

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});

// save the selection to updated the selected state
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  foodTypeSelected.innerHTML = foodType.innerHTML;
  let secondSvg = foodTypeSelected.previousElementSibling;
  let blockTarget = document.querySelector('.rec-btn.selected').dataset.blockTarget;
  secondSvg.querySelector('.selected').classList.remove('selected');
  secondSvg.querySelector('#' + blockTarget).classList.add('selected');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.wrapper__inner+.wrapper__inner {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.rec-btn {
  display: block;
}

.rec-btn:hover rect {
  fill: red;
}

.rec-btn.selected rect {
  fill: cyan;
}

.block-name {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.block.selected {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select id="blocks" class="select">
    <option value="block1">Block 1</option>
    <option value="block2">Block 2</option>
    <option value="block3">Block 3</option>
    <option value="block4">Block 4</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="wrapper__inner">
    <div class="image__wrapper">
      <svg width="224px" height="224px" viewBox="0 0 224 224" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <title>Group</title>
        <g id="Crowd-Funding" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-1107.000000, -593.000000)" fill="#4163BB">
            <g id="Group" transform="translate(1107.000000, 593.000000)">
              <a class="rec-btn selected" href="" data-block-target="block1"><rect id="block1" class="block" x="112" y="0" width="112" height="112"></rect></a> 
              <a class="rec-btn" href="" data-block-target="block2"><rect id="block2" class="block" x="112" y="112" width="112" height="112"></rect></a>
              <a class="rec-btn" href="" data-block-target="block3"><rect id="block3" class="block" x="0" y="0" width="112" height="112"></rect></a>
              <a class="rec-btn" href="" data-block-target="block4"><rect id="block4" class="block" x="0" y="112" width="112" height="112"></rect></a>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>

      <div id="foods" class="block-name">Block 1</div>

      <button class="btn">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper__inner">
    <svg width="224px" height="224px" viewBox="0 0 224 224" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <title>Group</title>
      <g id="Crowd-Funding" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-1107.000000, -593.000000)" fill="#4163BB">
          <g id="Group" transform="translate(1107.000000, 593.000000)">
            <rect id="block1" class="block selected" x="112" y="0" width="112" height="112"></rect>
            <rect id="block2" class="block" x="112" y="112" width="112" height="112"></rect>
            <rect id="block3" class="block" x="0" y="0" width="112" height="112"></rect>
            <rect id="block4" class="block" x="0" y="112" width="112" height="112"></rect>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>

    <div id="foodsSelected" class="block-name">Block 1</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. works well. but the second part is how to do a save what I have selected to update the other map

Comment: Oh, i missed that but updated my answer now. Test it...